# Why the below code snippet is not giving compile time error?

Tags: java, static, final

After declaring a static final instance varibale, one ArrayList object is being assigned to it. But when I am adding one extra semi-colon, it is fine with the java compiler. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FinalExample {

    private static final List<String> foo = new ArrayList();; //double semicolons are fine with compiler

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(FinalExample.foo);//Result is - []
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting the empty statement to make the preceding assignment fail?

Comment: I searched the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/index.html) for some insight. But in fact, I can only find a section about the [_empty statement_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6), nothing about _empty declarations_. But be assured, it will be the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon ends a statement. So when you give multiple semicolons in java  the compiler thinks the second semicolon as en empty statement and does not complains for it.

Comment: The double semicolon in the question is not at the end of a _statement_. It's at the end of a _class member declaration_. In fact, statements would be illegal at this place.

Comment: Isn't declaration a statement ?

Comment: Not in this position, no.